# Invoke Razor Component in Partial view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have a Razor Pages application, and I followed this tutorial https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/

I have `Index.cshtml` that Invokes a partial view called `_details.cshtml`
Within that partial view I'm trying to invoke a Razor component like this:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Details>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

Events don't get fired but content does get rendered.
If I use

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Details>(RenderMode.Server))
```

The content doesn't even get rendered. On the other side, if I use either of the above in the `Index.cshtml` the component works perfectly.

Here is the Details component code

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

<h3>Event Binding</h3> <br /> <br />
<button @onclick=@ButtonClicked>Event Binding Example</button>  <br /> <br />
<button @onclick=@(() => Message = "Inline:Button Clicked")>Inline Event Binding</button> <br /> <br />
<p>Message: @Message</p>

@functions {
    private string Message { get; set; } = "";
    void ButtonClicked()
    {
        Message = "Button Clicked";
    }
}
```

Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: " if I use either of the above in the Index.cshtml the component works perfectly": Do you mean that both click events are triggered and the newly added content of the Message property is displayed instead of the old one...? I thought that Razor component in Razor Pages or MVC Apps are not interactive.

Comment: Yes, works as expected, in an interactive way. Only if I invoke it in 'Index.cshtml' not inside the '_details.cshtml' partial view

Comment: According to the provided tutorial , I added the relevant configuration and tested your code , the component in the partial view rendered and the event got fired . Here is my [demo](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EeC_e1kuRTpKseI04jovbyEBbGxwmV2INRZKrtB6aXFF3g?e=pAVKs1) ,you could refer to . If you still have the issue , could you share the demo that can reproduce the issue?